# Explain this joke: "Theoretical physicists will never schedule a meeting on Wednesday because it spoils two weekends"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, jokes

This is the context:

> Finally, I would say that, even within physics, philosophers are sort of like theoretical physicists, and
>   physicists are like experimental physicists. Experimental physicists don’t like theoretical physicists, because
>   what are the latter really doing?— a lot of mathematical noodling, and they don’t really work at all. The
>   experimentalists instead think they are getting results. The joke experimental physicists say is, “**Theoretical
>   physicists will never schedule a meeting on Wednesday because it spoils two weekends."**
>
> Source: The origins of the universe: why is there something rather than nothing?
>   (in the Annals of The New York Academy Of Sciences)

Can anyone explain this joke?

Comment: This question might be more fit for Physics SE. It is likely a dig at [position uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) in Quantum Mechanics, whereby matter doesn't have deterministic position, but rather wave functions that describe probability of existence at a location. In the same way that matter spills over into surrounding space, Wednesday equally spills over into the preceding Sunday and the following Saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Experimental physicists don’t like theoretical physicists, because [...] they don’t really work at all."

The joke is that theoretical physicists don't do any work. Usually the weekend is {Sat, Sun}. If you had a meeting on Saturday, you would spoil one weekend.  But for theoretical physicists the weekend is {wed, thu, fri, sat, sun, mon, tue, wed}.

So a having a meeting on Wednesday would "spoil two weekends".

There is no clever use of English or punning in this joke, nor is there any physics needed to understand it.